# Cannot mount FS to mountpoint after "storcli /c0/v4 del force"

Tags: raid

Timeline:

We have a /foo/bar_new FS on a CentOS 7.

We have an old /foo/bar FS on a HW raid.

We copied all the data to the /foo/bar_new FS, from the /foo/bar old FS.

We umounted /foo/bar (the old disk that is/was on HW RAID), removed it from fstab.

We updated the fstab with /foo/bar_new to /foo/bar (it is on another disk, this is the new FS, but it needs to be reachable via the old filesystems path).

We mounted the /foo/bar (but this is the new FS now on new disks).

We removed the HW raid with: "storcli /c0/v4 del force".

And here comes the fun part:

/foo/bar (the new FS with this old mountpoint) got umounted automatically!

We cannot mount the /foo/bar anymore (it should be the new FS, just changed the mount point in fstab from /foo/bar_new to /foo/bar).

We can only mount the new FS to /foo/bar_new, but not /foo/bar.

When we try to mount the new fs to the old fs path, mount command says it mounted the FS to /foo/bar, but in reality it didn't.

**Q:** why?

Comment: "We unmounted /foo/bar" and "/foo/bar got unmounted automatically": What is the truth? And did you unmount /foo/bar_new before changing the fstab entry?

Comment: Did you, after each step. make sure it really succeeded? What does `mount` and `df` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick reboot solved the problem!